# What can be a function where $x \neq 2, y \neq 1$ for all $x,y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, rational-functions

I am trying to find a possible function to this graph below.

[image]

I am really bad with graphs so if anyone can further elaborate the ways to help identify graphs, I will deeply appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Looks like the plot of $xy=1$, but translated.

Also, this looks like a homework so please it a try first.

Answer (score 0):

You might notice that the function

$$y = \frac 1 x$$

looks "kind of" like this, except $x,y$ can never be zero. On top of that, you play with the expression a little, you might notice that, if we have

$$y = \frac{1}{x-a}$$

for any particular $a$, then $x$ can never be equal to $a$ because the denominator is undefined.

And then you realize for the $y=1/x$ equation that "$y$ cannot be this value $b$" is just translating the graph of $y$ by $b$ units vertically. And thus,

$$y = \frac{1}{x} + b$$

gives you a general function where $x$ is never $0$, $y$ is never $b$.

How might you combine these two ideas to form a function such that $x \neq a, y \neq b$ for all $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Does rendering 

$$\frac 1 x$$ 

undefined leave the entire equation invalid? 

As in for the case of 

$$y = \frac{1}{x} + b$$

Comment: The issue of whether it would be invalid is a nuanced issue that would require a lot of explanation to explain. But essentially, since you are considering only real numbers $x$ as the input to the function, it would only be undefined at $0$. It does not render the equation "invalid," though, it just means that if $x=0$, you cannot define a value for $y$ since it basically amounts to dividing by zero.

Comment: Thanks for a piece of your **rare candy** Eevee, i think i have evolved as a **graph trainer** slightly but surely.

Answer is $$y = \frac {1}{x-2} + 1$$

Comment: Yup! Glad I could help! ^_^